# Receiving a dictionary of files in FastAPI

Tags: python, http, python-requests, fastapi

The [documentation of FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/#multiple-file-uploads) gives a way of receiving multiple files:

```
@app.post("/uploadfiles/")
async def create_upload_files(files: List[UploadFile] = File(...)):
    ...
```

However, it's hard to keep track of the list's order in my application, since the number and content of files can change.
I would like to identify these files with keys, with something like a `Dict`:

```
@app.post("/uploadfiles/")
async def create_upload_files(files: Dict[str, UploadFile] = File(...)):
    ...
```

Would that work? If not, how could I do it?

(I want to send binary data and keep it as light as possible, so `json.dumps` or similar serialization functions are not acceptable.)